# Windows Server 2019 Std loses network when last user logs off

Tags: remote-desktop, internet-connection, windows-server-2019

I have a Windows Server 2019 Standard server that has a strange issue. During the logoff procedure of the last user connected through RDP, the server loses network capabilities.

When I log off, I see it logging off, and then my RDP connection changes to: I've lost connection while in connected state with a counter attempting to reconnect. From that moment on, closing and reopening RDP will just not work.

We have monitoring software running on the server and it too loses its connection.

The server (amongst many other that don't have this problem) is a guest VM in a proxmox environment. If I use Proxmox and start a console session, I get a login screen. When I log in, the problem is fixed, and I, and all other users, can RDP back in. If multiple users are logged in, and my admin user logs in and out, no problem. When the last user logs out, even with admin not logged in, the same happens and our monitoring software notifies of a lost connection.

If at this state I check console at the login screen, I see that windows thinks it is connected still. If I then use Proxmox, edit the VM to disconnect the network cable and plug it back in, the network card status goes to `disconnected`, to `connected, no internet`.

If I then login, the status goes to `connected`.

If I reboot the server, the problem seems to go away for a bit, but will return the same day.

EventLog does not show me anything that pinpoints this problem, but I may be missing it.

To my knowledge this started happening since last week but never happened before.

EDIT: Ran DISM and SFC /scannow, and it seems to have repaired something. Did not yet work afterwards, but rebooted. Have to wait a day to know for sure. Will update this question monday.

Comment: Did you try testing [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html)? And checking the network driver in the VM?

Comment: @harrymc DISM and SFC did repair something, network drivers are ok. Problem is still there though. I will attempt a reboot and see if that was necessary, but can't test until next week, given that after a reboot it usually is fine for half a day or so.

Comment: I don't believe in repairs done by these utilities. I would suggest a Repair Install with an In-place Upgrade.

Comment: @harrymc problem seems to have been resolved. Care to write your suggestion up as an answer? Then I'll gladly accept it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The poster tested Windows integrity by running
[Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html)
and then
[sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html). Some problems were found and fixed by the utilities.

The fact that errors were found is a red flag, as the ability of these
utilities to fix errors is limited.

In order to return Windows and all its components to a known and coherent
state, I counsel in such a case to
[Do a Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).

In the context of this post, the Repair Install finally and fully fixed
the problem.

Note that the Repair Install operation is equivalent to doing a major
upgrade of Windows, so the same precautions are counseled.